# Automated evaluation of SOLID principles enforcement

Tags: oop, automated-refactoring

Are there tools that can automatically evaluate the degree to which SOLID principles of OO design are respected in a project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

The principles of SOLID are higher-level concepts than a computer can be aware of.  Things like LSP can't be verified by a computer short of running a piece of code with every conceivable input.  And SRP can't be mechanically verified at all.

Answer (score 0):

SOLID principles are for humans who are telling the computers what to do with the input they get till the complete evolution of AI :). Pick up Single Responsibility Principle and elaborate the class which opens database connection, fetch the data and push data content to web service endpoint as JSON data. If one day, another data source is added or web service API format changes , class would be changed. Those changes might affect the implementation other classes in the same project  as well, so we should consider beforehand what might be required in future from our software.